# Communication between react and API (nodejs)

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I'm trying to get a post from my API (nodejs) with a simple form in react.
Its quite simple:

In my API I have this:

```
app.post("/api/register", (req, res) => {
        console.log("the nickname post is " + req.body.nickname);
    });
```

And my form in react:

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form action="http://localhost:8080/api/register" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="nickname" /><br />
        <input type="submit" />
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

It says that nodejs cannot read property `req.body.nickname`.
I probably didn't get something but I don't know what.

Comment: Please show the result of `console.log(req, res)`

Comment: it says this : TypeError: Cannot read property 'nickname' of undefined

Comment: No, instead of this `console.log("the nickname post is " + req.body.nickname);` write this `console.log(req, res)` and remove other code that accesses `nickname` if any. Then write the resulted console logs here.

Comment: `req.body` should not be `undefined` man, please check your  middleware `app.use()` with `body-parser`

Comment: it says this : "req => [object Object] res => [object Object]"

Comment: You should not `console.log(req, res)` (very complicated), please `console.log(req.body)`, it should not be `undefined`, if it's `undefined`, please check your middleware

Comment: well I got undefined for req.body in the console log

Comment: I dont have app.use() in my nodejs, is that a problem to get req.body ?

Comment: Ok it works now, its because i needed that "const urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false});" and i passed it as parameter to app.post.

Answer (score 0):

From W3 schools it seems the form should look like this - notice you are missing the value property

```
<form action="/action_page.php" method="post">
  First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
  Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: mu form in react is ok because it sends correctly, the problem comes from nodejs, not from react